# How to select links but not child links in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

How in jQuery can I select just the links inside a div element and not the child div elements contained within that div?

```
<div>
    <a>Link 1</a>
    <a>Link 2</a>
    <div>
        <a>Not these 1</a>
        <a>Not these 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

use the direct child selector >

e.g

```
$('div>a')
```

**UPDATE:**
 to appease Mr RoBorg

If you do have anchors inside nested elements inside the first div then the following will work. 
This uses a filter to ensure that the parent div is indeed the div you are targetting rather than a nested div.

[Demo](http://pastebin.me/496c8121962f9)

```
  var firstDivAnchors = $('div a').filter( function(){
        return $(this).closest('div').is('#yourDiv');
  });
```

Comment: Not quite... this won't get <div><span><a>...  which the question suggests it should

Comment: he said a divs links, not a div spans links.

Answer (score 6):

If there is a specific div you want to target, you can try:

`$("div#mydiv a :not(div a)");`

EDIT: It would be great if you post some more context (HTML) :)

Comment: that will always give 0 results

Comment: It is working on my site (www.viajeros.com). Try it in firebug: $("div#footer a :not(div a)");

Comment: I think it works by virtue of CSS selectors weight: "div#something" weights more than only "div"

Comment: @Danita - you need to check your markup at w3c, many errors (240+) which will mean strange selector results

Comment: your #footer does in fact have 0 anchor tags without being in child divs, your above selector reports 2

Comment: @redsquare Special care has been taken to conform to w3c recommendations. Also we are checking our pages with HTML Tidy for Firefox. We have 20 warnings (not 240+, not errors) in the homepage, most of which are from code we're required to keep verbatim and for special markup for WAI-ARIA.

Comment: @redsquare As for the specific question of this thread, you're right. I was wrong.

Comment: @Danita go here http://tinyurl.com/98g2u7 your site has 247 Errors, 29 warning(s)....

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember quite well, but doesn't children() does this work?

$(thisDiv).children('a')

In docs.jquery.com it reads:
children()
Get a set of elements containing all of the unique immediate children of each of the matched set of elements.

Comment: Yeah children or > is the same - Direct Children

Comment: true, but as far as I know the difference is that using children doesn't use a regex to deconstruct the selector, but both are good approaches.

Answer (score 1):

I think Danita was on the right track, but her sample did not work for me either. Using .not(), however, did work:

Given:

```
<div id="testdiv">
    <span><a>span a</a></span> <a>a</a>
    <div>
        <a>div a</a><span><a>div span a</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

find only a tags not nested inside nested divs.

```
var test = $('#testdiv').find('a').not('#testdiv div a');
$(test).each(function(){
    trace( $(this).html());
});
```

Not only will it ignore a tags inside the nested div, it will NOT ignore the a tags nested in spans.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need and looked around. Inspired by a few answers here I wrote this

```
$('div a').not('div div a')
```

I have tested this and it works! :-)

Comment: But it won't filter out links that are nested even further down. redsquare's answer seems better.